# Smarter way to use array entry value as key

Tags: php

Do you know a smarter way to use an array entry value as key?

Consider this array:

```
$array = [
    0 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'Title 1',
    ],
    2 => [
        'id' => 2,
        'title' => 'Title 1',
    ],
    3 => [
        'id' => 3,
        'title' => 'Title 1',
    ]
];
```

To replace each array key with value of `id` I do this:

```
$new_array = [];

foreach ($array AS $item) {
    $new_array[$item['id']] = $item;
}

unset($array);
```

Comment: [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) & [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), or your way which is fine.

Comment: Just checked how Laravel executes it's collection->keyBy() method and the logic is exactly the same as yours. They just encapsulate everything into a helper function which accepts either prop name or callback for determining the key.

Comment: How big are the arrays you are working with?

Comment: @bishop The array are +10.000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$array = array_column($array, null, 'id');
```

Look at the description of the `column_key` and `index_key` arguments: http://php.net/array_column.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment by Lawrence

```
$ids = array_column($array, 'id');
$array = array_combine($ids, $array);
```